# Why my angular components containing div shifts/moves up when component is rendered first time using routing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am developing an Angular 10 app. I have a page with

- navigation bar on top,
- an image banner on left half of page, and
- login/signup form on right half of page

I am using `<router-outlet>` for **right half** to route through different child components for step by step sign up.
When my app routes to one of the child components which contains **ng-otp-input**, both the left and right divs of the page shifts/moves up. **If I hit F5, page shows correctly.**
For other child component this issue is not seen. This issue does not occur when I remove ng-otp-input component.
Below is the html for the page.

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
  <some-banner></some-banner>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Below is the top navigation bar html

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="https://abc.in/" target="_blank">
            <img class="logo" src="assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Next, left image banner component

```
<div class="left">
    <img [src]="imageURL"/>
    <div style="display: block; font-weight: bold; font-size: 48px; color: #1A1A1A;">Make learning fun!</div>
    <div style="display: block; font-size: 28px; ">Any subject, in any language, on any device, for all ages!</div>
    <div style="display: block; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color: #1A1A1A; padding-top:20px">or download the
        app:</div>
    <div class="flex social-btns">...</div>
</div>
```

Last, right div which contains form

```
<div class="form">

  <form nz-form [formGroup]="otpConfirmationForm">
    <nz-form-item></nz-form-item>
    <nz-form-item class="title">Forgot Password</nz-form-item>

    <nz-form-item class="forgotPasswordDescription">
      {{descriptionMessage}}
    </nz-form-item>

    <nz-form-item>...</nz-form-item>

    <nz-form-item class="subtitle">
      Confirmation code
    </nz-form-item>

    <nz-form-item>
      <ng-otp-input #ngOtpInput (onInputChange)="onOtpChange($event)" [config]="config">
      </ng-otp-input>
    </nz-form-item>
  </form>
</div>
```

For reference, find screenshots before and after div shifting up.

- [Before shifting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWhBz.png)
- [After shifting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f5mv.png)

Comment: I think that you should move the divs 'rigth' and 'left' to the main.component, but it's only an idea, I really don't know waht happend because I don't know about your class -if your "content" class use flex and align-items end or start, etc

Comment: Luckily I stumbled upon a temporary fix. It seems that ng-otp-input component was causing the issue. If I set disableAutoFocus to true in the [config]="config", this div shifting issue get resolved.